Kandy - Histograms don't work - Unresolved reference: histogram
I tried to reproduce the simple Kotlin Kandy histogram example at https://kotlin.github.io/kandy/histogram-simple.html.
val random = java.util.Random(42)

val dataframe = dataFrameOf(
    "sample" to List(1000) { random.nextGaussian() }
)

dataframe.plot {
    histogram("sample")
}

However, I get the error:
Unresolved reference: histogram

It seems like the unit tests depend on import org.jetbrains.kotlinx.statistics.kandy.layers.histogram, but I can't find that class anywhere and IntelliJ won't resolve the import.
I'm using these dependencies in a desktop Kotlin project:
dependencies {
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kandy-lets-plot:0.7.1")
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kandy-echarts:0.7.1")
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kandy-util:0.7.1")
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kandy-api:0.7.1")
}

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Try demo simple histogram in Kotlin desktop project with main function

Expected behavior
Histogram should be generated:

Actual Behavior
Application doesn't build - it can't find histogram
**Related
I opened a bug for this on the Kandy GitHub repo at https://github.com/Kotlin/kandy/issues/443

@Sweeper No, but I just tried that and Maven Central doesn't have that artifact. Is it hosted at another repo?

Thank you, that worked! I had to do some searching at https://packages.jetbrains.team/maven/p/kds/kotlin-ds-maven/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlin-statistics-jvm/ for the latest stable version, which as of Oct 2024 is 0.3.1. Please add as the answer and I'll accept!

@Sweeper do you know where the source code for org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlin-statistics-jvm is?

According to this page, you need an extra dependency for the things in the org.jetbrains.kotlinx.statistics package.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://packages.jetbrains.team/maven/p/kds/kotlin-ds-maven")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kandy-lets-plot:0.7.0")

    // this below!
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlin-statistics-jvm:0.3.1")
}


Thanks for pointing to the docs. I recall seeing that now, although at the time I didn't realize that the histogram functionality needed the statistics package. This fixes it!
